# implemented compare but got exception when calling Arrays.sort

Tags: java, comparator

Here is my class:

```
public static class __9_7_Person implements Comparator<__9_7_Person> {
    private int height;
    private int weight;
    public __9_7_Person(int height, int weight) {
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public int compare(__9_7_Person p1, __9_7_Person p2) {
        if (p1.height != p2.height) {
            return p1.height - p2.height;
        }
        else {
            return p1.weight - p2.weight;
        }
    }
}
```

I then created an array like this:

```
__9_7_Person p[] = {new __9_7_Person(60, 100),
                    new __9_7_Person(70, 150),
                    new __9_7_Person(56, 90),
                    new __9_7_Person(75, 190),
                    new __9_7_Person(60, 95),
                    new __9_7_Person(68, 110),
};
```

But got exception when I called Arrays.sort(p): "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ch_9$__9_7_Person cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Comment: I hope these aren't the actual names of your classes, with the underscores and all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement `Comparable` for a *natural* ordering, in which case you don't need to pass a separator comparator into `Arrays.sort`. *Or* you could implement `Comparator<__9_7_Person>` (probably in a separate class, e.g. `HeightWeightPersonComparator`) and call:

```
Arrays.sort(p, new HeightWeightPersonComparator());
```

It's important to understand the difference between `Comparable` and `Comparator`. A `Comparable` implementation says "I know how to compare myself to another object of an appropriate type" - where a `Comparator` implementation says "I know how to compare two objects of appropriate types".

Obviously any type can only implement `Comparable` once (within reason), whereas there can be any number of `Comparator` implementations. Using a separate `Comparator` is more flexible unless there's an "obvious" comparison you should use. If you don't specify a `Comparator`, `Arrays.sort` will assume that each of the elements in the array can compare itself with other elements of the array, i.e. they implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 8):

You implemented Comparator, not Comparable. You should implement Comparable instead of Comparator.

As stated [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface.

Comparators are useful if you want to be able to have different sorting order for the same class. In this case, Comparable can't be used

Comment: +1, added the quote from `Arrays.sort` that specifies that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `java.lang.Comparable` interface, not the `java.util.Comparator` interface.